# Why C++ CGI form_iterator values not getting in XMLHttpRequest asynchronous Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, html, c++, ajax, cgi

I wrote a sample HTML page with Ajax script . I have a .cgi file in cpp which will accept values from ajax and send message back to HTML page . Now i am facing the problem that i didn't get values in cgi script . This is my code :

`HTML & ajax` script :

```
<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript">

var XMLHttp;

if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {

        XMLHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

} else {
        XMLHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function SentData () {

    var name = document.getElementById('name').value ;
    var postData;

    XMLHttp.open("POST", "simplecgi.cgi", true);

    postData = "";
    postData += name;

    XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    XMLHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);

    XMLHttp.send(postData);

    XMLHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = XMLHttp.responseText;   

    }

}
</script>

<h1>Simple application</h1>

    <form id="newform">
        Enter Name <input onkeyup = "javascript: SentData()" name ="name" id="name">
    </form>

<div id = "area">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here `SentData`  function get `textarea` value and append with `postdata` and send it via `XMLHttpRequest` .

and the `cpp cgi` script :

```
include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "cgicc/Cgicc.h"
#include "cgicc/HTTPHTMLHeader.h"
#include "cgicc/HTMLClasses.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cgicc;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

Cgicc cgi;  

try {
       // Send HTTP header
      cout << HTTPHTMLHeader() << endl; 
      // Set up the HTML document
      cout << html() << head(title("cgi sample")) << endl;
      cout << body() << endl;

      form_iterator name = cgi.getElement("name");

      if( name != cgi.getElements().end()){

        cout << "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n"<< **name << "sucess"<<endl;
        cout << body() << html();

    }
    catch(exception& e) { }

return 0 ;

}
```

Here i want to get HTML text area value and then i am sending that value with sucess message back to HTML .

The problem i am facing now is i didn't get that   `form_iterator name = cgi.getElement("name");`value . This is empty ? Why ?

But this is working fine when i use like

```
<form id="newform" action="simplecgi.cgi" method="POST">
            Enter Name <input onkeyup = "javascript: SentData()" name ="name" id="name">
        </form>
```

I don;t want to redirect my HTML page to .cgi page . For that i am using ajax . Why this error ? any suggestions ?

if I didn't use `<form >` like simply a text area with out form tag . Can i pass this textarea values to .cgi and get message back to HTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, by definition, has to be encoded using this convention.

Your javascript code appears to blindly put a bare string value in the body of the `POST`. That's not the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

The format, roughly summarizing, is a list of "name=value" pairs, separated by ampersands, with each `value` %-encoded like in a `URL`, hence "urlencoded". Your javascript code sends just the `value` part, and fails to %-encode it altogether.

Fix your javascript so that the `POST`-ed content is correctly encoded. In general, it's going to be much easier to use any one of the freely available Javascript libraries to do all the work for you, like `Jquery`, instead of reinventing the wheel yourself.

Comment: How can i pass along ampersands ? any example ?

Comment: if i pass  `simplecgi.cgi?name=Mary+Jones`   can i get this values inside  `form_iterator name = cgi.getElement("name");` ?

Comment: `simplecgi.cgi?name=Mary+Jones` is working fine ..thanks